# Please help me with absolute position style

Tags: react-native

I have a trouble with click and focus, when I'm using position absolute in the style. The click and focus is working only purple position (view one), and doesn't work in the white position (view two).

Here is the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3yIg.jpg

Sorry my bad english.

I tried use zIndex, unsuccessfully ;(

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <View style={styles.containerText}>
            <TextInput placeholder="Entre com alguma coisa :D" style={styles.textInput} />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <Text>Container</Text>
          <TextInput placeholder="Entre com alguma coisa :D" />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },

  header: {
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: '#537',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  body: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },

  containerText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: '-20%',
  },

  textInput: {
    borderWidth: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: add `zIndex:5` or `elevation:3` in `containerText`

Comment: Did not work ;(

Answer (score 0):

Replace the style and check

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },

    header: {
        height: 150,
        backgroundColor: '#537',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    body: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },

    containerText: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 150 - 20 
    },

    textInput: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        height: 40
    }
});
```